# Template logic to address a third URL segment

Tags: templating, segments

I'm using Craft 3, and I'm struggling to make sense of how to address the following. (I've not had need to venture into a third URL segment before.)

I have a url of the form:

`stories/{slug}`

served by a template:

`stories/_entry`

I'm aware that the 'entry' variable gets set automatically. So far so basic.

But I also want to address urls of the form:

`stories/{slug}/{variable}`

…where `variable` is used to fetch content from a specific Matrix row in the entry that matches `slug`.

It is important that `variable` forms a third segment addressable as its own page, and not just a URL query parameter.

I have tried 2 approaches:

---

1. Getting segment 3 and then using it in a **conditional** inside of `stories/_entry`:

`{% set seg3 = craft.app.request.getSegment(3) %}
{% if seg3|length %}
    {% include 'partials/extract' %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'partials/story' %}
{% endif %}`

…but when seg3 is not empty Craft says:

> Template not found

---

2. Setting a **route** to a different template:

`stories/{slug}/{*}`

…is processed by:

`stories/_extract`

…in which, as a basic test I have:

```
{% block meta %}
    <title>{{ entry.title }}</title>
{% endblock %}
```

…but Craft then reports a Twig runtime error, saying:

> Variable "entry" does not exist

So I tried using:

```
{% set seg2 = craft.app.request.getSegment(2) %}
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('stories').slug(seg2).all() %}
    {% block meta %}
        <title>{{ entry.title }}</title>
    {% endblock %}
{% endfor %}
```

…but that makes no difference.

---

Is my approach 2 definition of `entry` wrong?

Why does a non-empty value in segment 3 cause approach 1 to fail?

I'm obviously missing something fundamental here. Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: I note that approach 2 is exactly what is advocated at https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4675/3507. And yet, for me, it doesn't work. Perhaps something is different under Craft 3 I haven't Twigged (groan) to yet.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you look into using Craft's Advanced Routing functionality to accomplish this.

For instance, add the following to your `config/routes.php`:

```
'stories/<slug:\w+>/?<option:\w+>?' => ['template' => '_extract'],
```

This will then populate the `_extract` template with the twig variable `{{ slug }}` and also the `{{ option }}` variable, if it exists.

Then in your twig template you can grab the entry and check for the existence of the option variable thus:

```
    {% set entry = craft.entries.section('stories').slug(slug).one() %}

    {% if entry %}
            <h1>Entry title is: {{ entry.title }}</h1>
    {% endif %}

    <h2>Slug is: {{ slug }} </h2>

    {% if option is defined %}
            <h3>Option is: {{ option }}</h3>
    {% endif %}
```

I'd recommend reading the docs on Advanced routing as it's quite a powerful feature: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/routing.html#advanced-routing

Comment: Belated thanks for this, Piaras. With Brad @ P&T's help on a support ticket, I'd already arrived at my fundamental mistake which was setting entry with .all() instead of .one(), and then everything fell into place. I just hadn't properly grasped when to use those methods, but the newly revised v3 docs are [a lot clearer](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/element-queries.html#all).